# I want remove file extension or rename the file extension before uploaded in php codeigniter

Tags: file, codeigniter, upload, rename

when user select the file then in server side file extension will be removed or rename and uploaded it to the server using php codeigniter library

Answer (score 0):

This should remove your file extension

```
<?php 
  $var = "testfile.php"; 
  $explode = explode( '.', $var ); 
  array_pop( $explode); 
  $var = implode( '.', $explode ); 
  var_dump( $var );
```

As for uploading you will need to read the manual on file uploading

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Comment: yea got it but how its possible using $this->upload->do_upload() this will be upload the file on the server...

Comment: Are the users uploading a file to your server?

Comment: $this->upload->do_upload()  this will do the upload the file on the server but i wants that file extension have to be changes and that should be uploaded...

Comment: In that case read the link I provided and you will find all the information you need in there.  No one is going to write all the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

file name can be changed using the following codes:

```
$your_given_name = time().rand().$_FILES["userfiles"]['name'];
$config['file_name'] = $your_given_name;
```

for changing extension you can use:

```
 if ($this->upload->do_upload('file_name')) {
          $file_data=$this->upload->data();
          $new_name_by_you='anything'.$file_data['file_ext'];
          $new_path=$file_data['file_path'].$new_name_by_you;
          rename($file_data['full_path'],  $new_path);
    }
```

rename() is a php built in function. for details please visit http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

Answer (score 0):

I recently just had the same issue, and found it really annoying that even when you specified a file_name in code igniter it would append the file extension. Which i did not want.

Blinkydamo's link is not helpfull, since that is the link i was following in the first place and makes no mention of this dilema, although it does demontrate that it is not possible idrectly through Code Igniter - by ommission of the answer.

I haven't tried md asif rahman's method, but it looks sound.

Alternatively you can just forget about using Code Igniter's upload function, and fall back onto PHPs standard one, which is what I have done :

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['imageFile']['tmp_name'], '/path/'.$filename);
```

where $filename is the exact name of the file including extension, therefore if none is specified - it wont have one.

Answer (score 0):

it is so easy

change code in
libraries/Upload.php

```
public function set_filename($path, $filename)
{
    if ($this->encrypt_name === TRUE)
    {
        $filename = md5(uniqid(mt_rand()));
    }

    if ($this->overwrite === TRUE OR ! file_exists($path.$filename))
    {
        return $filename;
    }


    $filename = str_replace($this->file_ext, '', $filename);
    $new_filename = '';
    for ($i = 1; $i < $this->max_filename_increment; $i++)
    {
        if ( ! file_exists($path.$filename.$i))
        {
            $new_filename = $filename.$i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ($new_filename === '')
    {
        $this->set_error('upload_bad_filename', 'debug');
        return FALSE;
    }
    else
    {
        return $new_filename;
    }
}
```